# Написанная функция работает, если вызывается из Sub, но не работает на листе

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица в книге Excel, состоящая из двух колонок: в первой колонке номера, а во второй фамилии.

Написал функцию для получения фамилии по номеру *get_family2*, но она не работает, если записать ее в ячейку (возвращает ошибку `#ЗНАЧ!`).

Если вызывать функцию *get_family2* из макроса `Sub`то она работает.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы функция работала при написании в ячейку.**

```
Public Function get_family2(table_num As Integer)
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook, FSO As Object, sSourceFileName As String, sPathToSourceFile As String
    Dim Rng As Range, NameOfOrganization As String, ACT_Num As String
    
    
    sSourceFileName = "D:\files\tabel_nums.xlsx" 'название файла источника (должен лежать в той же папке, что и Акт)
    
    
    sPathToSourceFile = sSourceFileName 'ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & sSourceFileName
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(sSourceFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    

    With SourceWB.Worksheets(1)
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A5")
    If cell.Value = table_num Then
    out = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
    Next cell
    
   
    End With
    MsgBox out
    SourceWB.Close (False) 'закрываем файл
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    get_family2 = out
End Function

Sub prosto()
 
 Dim x
 get_family2 (156)
 End Sub
```

Так же поиск номера пытался сделать через Find, но на этой строке выходила ошибка Run-time error 13: Type mismatch

```
Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(table_num, xlValues, xlWhole)
```

[image: вот так выглядит эксель, откуда получаются данные]

[image: При вводе функции get_family2() в ячейку]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция листа не может открывать другие файлы. Да и не нужно, чтобы функция выполняла несколько операций, это не процедура *Sub*. А Вы заставляете ее открывать файл, брать данные, закрывать файл.

Зачем что-то придумывать, писать *UDF*, когда для такой задачи можно использовать родную, встроенную функцию?

```
=ВПР(таб_номер;диапазон;2;0)
```

где *таб_номер* - ссылка на ячейку с табельным номером; *диапазон* - ссылка на диапазон книги, из которой нужно получить ФИО  (столбец1 - номера, столбец2 - ФИО).

Открыть две книги. В первой написать формулу со ссылкой на диапазон другой книги. Путь к книге прописывать не нужно, достаточно при написании формулы перейти в книгу-источник и выделить нужный диапазон. После завершения редактирования формулы книгу-источник можно закрыть. При закрытой книге-источнике путь к ней автоматически прописывается в формуле